# How to get referenced data from another sheet to update

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am referencing several cells from one sheet to another. In an attempt to compile specific data. What is occurring is that when the data from the 'CL Upcoming' sheet is modified, the data on the 'Email' tab is not updating. I have tried refreshing the document with ctrl+alt+shift+F9 but it does not update the data.

Below in the illustration, all of the data is outdated and not referencing the current data from the 'CL Upcoming' sheet.

[image]

Comment: So cell J44 in CL Upcoming has a value other than 6/13/2022? Does that sheet have a table with filters set and/or does it have merged cells?

Comment: Did you check the Excel Options: Formulas settings, and did you try just F9 by itself?